# Skeleton css til page complete loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a skeleton css til the page is full loaded. I thought this solution. So if javascript is disable i wont have any problem. Thats correct? Maybe u have a better solution? THX!

```
 .slider {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .slider2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #red;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
      animation: fading 2s infinite;
      z-index: 1;
    }



 <div class="slider" style="display: none;"><div class="slider2"></div></div>


$(() => {

    const ph = $('.slider');


    let toggleEffect = () => {
      ph.show();
      $(window).on('load', function() {
        ph.hide();
      });
    };

    toggleEffect();

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

please try `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ph.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thx for ur reply. What the difference?

Comment: because `window.load` event call before page loading start and `document.ready` event call after your page ready

Comment: But, i have 2 elements, 1 the real element with the content "box" and 1 element with the skeleton css "slider". I try ur code but nothing happens.